# create employee details using structures

Tags: function, loops, if-statement

Create a structure to represent employee details such as name, age, employee ID, salary,
designation, phone number, and permanent address. Use a substructure for salary with members
like basic salary, DA, and HRA. Implement a menu-driven program that allows the user to
perform the following operations using an array of structures to create an employee database:
i. Read employee details by calling a user-defined function getEmployeeInfo().
ii. Display all employees who have the same designation with the help of a function
searchByDesignation().
iii. Update salary details and designation for a promoted employee using the function
updateEmployee().
The program should provide a menu with options for the user to choose from, and based on the
selected option, it should perform the corresponding operation. Please note that you will need to
implement the functions getEmployeeInfo(), searchByDesignation(), and updateEmployee()
according to the specified requirements

as by above details given by i wanted a c code without using pointers